What fuses should I set without a boot loader with arduino nano 328pb?
What fuses should I set in order to use all the 32768 byte of Flash memory correctly?

What do you mean with "correctly"? You don't need to set fuses to use the 328 without a bootloader.

For instance, I have to disable BOOTRST to use memory of boot loader. You won’t see any problem in most cases, until firmware size is comparatively small.
My Arduino Nano won’t start with firmware of size more than 30720 bytes until I disable BOOTRST.
Playing with BOOTSZ1 and BOOTSZ0 also spares some more bytes.
However, I can’t find ultimate manual how to be able to use all the 32768 bytes.

Using the "minicore" Arduino core is the recommended way of using an Atmega328PB chip (or indeed an Atmega328p chip) with Arduino environment if you do not require a bootloader. It will set the fuses correctly for no bootloader operation.
https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore

You disable BOOTRST. That's it. The "ultimate manual" you refer to is the datasheet which is currently at https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf.
If that link doesn't work, try Googling "atmega328 datasheet".
